# Data Structure for Quickly Checking Numbers against Overlapping Ranges

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let's say I have the following number ranges:

0-500
0-100
75-127
125-157
130-198
198-200

Now, let's say I need to be able to check any given number and see which ranges it is in.  What sort of data structure would be used most efficiently to tell that, say, the number 100 belongs to the ranges 0-500, 0-100, and 75-127?  Do I just want a binary tree holding the starting values?  In that case, would it be feasible for each node in the tree to hold several objects containing each range at that starting point?

Note that I only need to retrieve for this particular application, I don't really see myself needing to modify it mid-process, so retrieval speed is by far my priority.

Thanks!

Comment: You want it to work for this input only ?

Comment: No, for any inputs and ranges.

Comment: Is it okay to create your own data structure ?

Comment: Ideally, I need to be able to retrieve from up to 1000 different ranges in well under 100ms.

Comment: do you actually store the numbers. Meaning if you just want to check if a number will fit a particular range or you want to check if a number is actually stored in a range?

Comment: They will be accessed dynamically multiple times in rapid succession, but they will be retrieved from objects which hold them.  Those objects need to use the data for their own calculations, but the data is also needed to decide whether the calculations are necessary.  Right now, I am iterating through all existing objects, but my goal is to use the data structure to decide which objects need to be accessed.  That is why I believe the data needs to be preloaded into a structure.

Comment: And is it possible that a data which is supposed to fit into a range not be present in that range?. For example in your case `100` will fit into first three ranges. So if present, will it be present in all three ranges?

Comment: If that solution provides optimum access time, that is perfectly acceptable.  I saw your original answer about making several hash tables, and planned on using a derivative of it.  I have used the exact method you suggested in the past and it worked well, it just didn't come to mind tonight.  If you have another idea that could work better though, I would love to see what it is.

Comment: Sort the start ranges, sort the end ranges, use a binary search to find the valid ranges on the left of the "start" list and the valid ranges on the right of the "end" list. then intersect. Obviously each item in the sorted lists needs to point back to the original range. Eh... but I don't know if you can sort and then get this done in under 100 ms.

Comment: @JS: I deleted my answer since I thought you are not storing the keys anywhere. If you are storing the keys, then my approach looks reasonable. But as suggested in another answer, `Interval trees` if it suits your needs, you would get exponential speedup compared to mine

Comment: @JS I updated my answer and wrote an explanation on how it works. The input is 10 times bigger than what you want, and still solved in less than 100 ms. The data structure used are: Tree Set and Tree Map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Interval trees are quite general concept and keep a slightly different data in nodes for every problem. In your case each node would keep a list of input intervals that cover the interval node is representing.

Comment: You might want to add this link which explains `interval tree` better than wikipedia.
http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/

Comment: This looks interesting and I'll be taking a close look at it.  Thanks for the suggestion, and thank you arun for the link!

Comment: This line in the link looks like what you exactly need.
`In the abstract, the query algorithm must do the following: Given an integer k and an interval tree T, list all the intervals stored in T that contain k. An interval [a,b] contains k if a <= k <= b.`

Comment: Would be the normal choice *except* if checking not construction of the data structure needs to be speed optimised then you can pre-compute the answer for all points within the ranges and do a simple table lookup as the check - see my Python solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let `R` denote the number of ranges possible. (For your example `R=6`)

Create `R` hashtables such that each hash table can hold only one range. For your example you need to create 6 hashtables. The first hash table `R1`will contain values from 0-500 only.

Populate hashtable.

Each number will go into appropriate hashtables. For your example number `100` will go into `R1`, `R2`, `R3`. If `R` is large, then you would need to create lot of hashtables. But then the total space is bounded by the actual data stored in all the hashtables put together.

Retrival:

For any given number check if it is present in each of the `R` hashtables. You can further optimize by choosing which hashtables to look. For example for `100` you only need to look into 3 out of 6 hashtables.

Time complexity:

Searching for a single value in a hash table takes `constant time` (on average). So
Amortized `O(1)` to see if a number is present in a hashtable.

Amortized `O(R)` to produce the output as we need to look at all the hashtables to produce the output

Comment: Thanks for posting this again!  This very well may work great, I haven't looked into Interval Trees yet though.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the "Time complexity" section means?  If it's not a brief explanation you don't need to devote more of your time to it of course, I can look it up I am sure. :)

Comment: @JS: You mean to ask what `Time complexity` actually means in general or `Time complexity` for this particular approach?

Comment: I do not know what the "Amortized O(R/1)" terms mean.

Comment: Classic example would be quick sort Vs MergeSort. Worst case time complexity of mergesort is `O(nlogn)` and worst case complexity of quicksort is `O(n^2)`. But in `practice` quicksort performs better than mergesort. Why? Because we need to look at the average case time complexity. Mergesort on average takes `O(nlogn)`, but quicksort on average takes `O(n)`. If you don't understand the word `amortized`, you can think of it as `average`

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

- Much faster
- Much more efficient in memory consumption
- For 1,000 input, it's guarantee it works in less than 100 ms in worst cases
- For 10 000 input ranges, **10x** more than the required input, it still works in less than 100 ms for 50 duplicates of `from` ex: {0 - #}x50 , {1 - #}x50 etc... for all `from` ranges.

**Goal**

Given 10,000 input range intervals (From to - To make the scenario worst, every 'from' is duplicated 50 times). The program takes one target value and displays all the ranges where the target belongs.

**Example on how it works for 4 ranges:**

Given the following ranges:

```
0 - 100
0 - 500
50 - 500
20 - 300
```

Target : 40

**Output**:

```
20 - 300
0 - 500
0 - 100
```

**Explanation of the Algorithm (using the previous example):**

Every `from` value is mapped to an `index++` starting from `index = 0`. So, in our example:

```
From => index
0 => 0
50 => 1
20 => 2
```

Now having an array of Tree Set called `pointers`, every index `i` of this array refers to the `key` of value `i` in the Tree Set. So `pointers[0]` refers to 'from': 0, `pointers[1]` refers to 'from': 50, `pointers[2]` refers to 'from': 20.

Now we add the `to` values to each `from` value respectively by looking at the tree map `'key' => 'value'` where `value` is the index of `key` in the `pointers` array.

Moreover, we want the `to` values added in the `pointers` array at every index to be sorted in a descending order (Later I explain why).

So now the pointer becomes like this:

```
index => TreeSet[values..]
0 => 500 | 100
1 => 500
2 => 300
```

Now we are ready to get the ranges where the target belongs to.

For `target = 40`

1 - Search for the closest floor key of 40 in the tree map. The program finds that 20 is the closest one.

2 - It goes to the index corresponding to 20 in the pointers array. To get the index of 20: look at the tree map at key 20. Index of 20 is 2.

3 - So go now to `pointers[2]`, it finds that there is the number 300.

4 - Now the application checks if 300 is less than target, the reason it does this, is because I mentioned before that every Tree Set created is sorted in a descending order. So if 300 is smaller than the target, therefore no need to continue checking for the next values in the `pointers[2]` because it's guarantee that they are smaller.

5 - In this case, 300 is greater than target, then print the key as `from` and `pointer[2] {current element}` as `to`.

6 - Since only one element found in `pointers[2]`, the for loop exits, and the key is removed from the tree map, so next time when the program wants to find the next closest floor key, it will find the next one, if it exists.

7 - (Next iteration of while loop) The next key found, after removing key 20, is 0, with index 0 according to the tree map.

8 - Go to `pointers[0]`. It finds that the number of elements in Tree Set at `pointers[0]` is 2.

9 - Start with the first element `pointers[0] {first element}`. Is 500 less than 40 ? No, print "range". Next element, is 100 less than 40 ? No, print "range". No more elements exit for loop.

10 - Remove key 0 from tree map.

11 - Now the While loop condition checks if there exist a closest floor key for the target. No, because 0 and 20 were removed. So condition not satisfied, exit while loop.

12 - Print time consumed, and end program :)

Hope you find the explanation useful.

**Code**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Interval {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int MAX_SIZE = 10000;
        int[] from = new int[MAX_SIZE];
        int[] to = new int[MAX_SIZE];

        //Generate 10,000 (from - to), with 50 redundant (from range) for every value of from. (to make the application heavy)
        int c = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
            from[i] = 0+c;
            to[i] = from[i] + (int)(Math.random()*100);
            if(i%50 == 0) 
                c++;
        }

        //Start time counting
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int target = 97;
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treePointer = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(); // will sotre <From, index++>

        int index = 0;
        int size = from.length;
        TreeSet<Integer>[] pointers = new TreeSet[size]; //Array of tree set to store values of every "from" range

        //insert into tree
        for(int i=0; i<from.length;i++){
            if(!treePointer.containsKey(from[i])){ //if the "from" does not exist in the tree yet, insert it
                treePointer.put(from[i], index);
                pointers[index++] = new TreeSet<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder()); //sort descending order
            }

            //index of "from" in the pointers array
            int virtualIndex = treePointer.get(from[i]);
            //add the 'to' element to the corresponding index of "from" in Tree Set at pointers[index of "from"]
            pointers[virtualIndex].add(to[i]);
        }

        // Display part of the pointers array to understand how elements are stored
//      for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
//          for(int current : pointers[i]){
//              System.out.print(current + " ");
//          }
//          System.out.println();
//      }

        //Start checking for the ranges
        Integer currentKey = -1; //dummy number at first
        while((currentKey = treePointer.floorKey(target)) != null){ // while there is a closest floor key
          //get index assigned to the closest floor key
            int virtualIndex = treePointer.get(currentKey);
            //loop on the elements found at pointers[index of closest floor number]
            for(int toValue : pointers[virtualIndex]){
                if(toValue < target) //remember the values are sorted in a descending order, so whenever the value becomes smaller than the target don't continue the for loop
                    break;
                System.out.println(currentKey + " - " + toValue); // else target less or equal to toValue, so print range
            }
            treePointer.remove(currentKey); //remove key from tree to fetch the next floor key in the next while iteration
        }
        //Display time consumed in ms
        System.out.println("\nTotal time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got little experience with Java and I'm not sure what exactly some of the imported objects/methods do, but that lookup time looks great and it's probably about the same number of separate lookups I'll need.  This definitely looks promising.

Comment: @Amir Bawab: Appreciate your effort in writing the code. But it it really hard to understand the algorithm behind your code. Can you add a pseudo-code?

Comment: Books tell us to write the logic first and then code, but sometimes we end up doing the opposite :)

Comment: Well I drew it on a white board before implementing it :)

Comment: @arunmoezhi better now ?

Comment: @AmirBawab: Much better. I need to spend sometime reading your algorithms :)

Comment: I updated my answer, now it's faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have enough memory, I would use an array of lists, where the list is of all ranges containing the index.

Here is a Python solution showing the algorithm in more detail:

```
# (Inclusive) ranges
ranges = [(0,500), (0,100), (75,127), (125,157), (130,198), (198,200)]
smallest = min(r[0] for r in ranges)
largest  = max(r[1] for r in ranges)

# Ceate table
table = [[] for i in range(smallest, largest+1)] # List of lists
for r in ranges: # pre-compute results
    mn, mx = r
    for index in range(mn, mx+1):
        table[index - smallest].append(r)

def check(n):
    'Return list of ranges containing n'
    if smallest <= n <= largest:
        return table[n - smallest]
    else:
        return []   # Out of range

for n in [-10, 10, 75, 127, 129, 130, 158, 197, 198, 199, 500, 501]:
    print('%3i is in groups: %r' % (n, check(n)))
```

The output is:

```
-10 is in groups: []
 10 is in groups: [(0, 500), (0, 100)]
 75 is in groups: [(0, 500), (0, 100), (75, 127)]
127 is in groups: [(0, 500), (75, 127), (125, 157)]
129 is in groups: [(0, 500), (125, 157)]
130 is in groups: [(0, 500), (125, 157), (130, 198)]
158 is in groups: [(0, 500), (130, 198)]
197 is in groups: [(0, 500), (130, 198)]
198 is in groups: [(0, 500), (130, 198), (198, 200)]
199 is in groups: [(0, 500), (198, 200)]
500 is in groups: [(0, 500)]
501 is in groups: []
```

Further optimisations such as using a bit-set to store what ranges are at each index instead of a list are possible.

From the comments below, I decided to modify the above to choose between the table lookup method above and a slower but vastly more memory efficient solution based on direct comparison. (Ideally there would be an interval tree based solution included too):

```
# (Inclusive) ranges
ranges = [(0,500), (0,100), (75,127), (125,157), (130,198), (198,200)]
limit = 1000000 # Or whatever

smallest = min(r[0] for r in ranges)
largest  = max(r[1] for r in ranges)

if (largest - smallest) * len(ranges) < limit:
    # Ceate table
    table = [[] for i in range(smallest, largest+1)] # List of lists
    for r in ranges:
        mn, mx = r
        for index in range(mn, mx+1):
            table[index - smallest].append(r)

    def check(n):
        'Return list of ranges containing n'
        if smallest <= n <= largest:
            return table[n - smallest]
        else:
            return []   # Out of range
else:
    # mpre emory efficient method, for example
    def check(n):
        return [(mn, mx) for mn, mx in ranges if mn <= n <= mx]

for n in [-10, 10, 75, 127, 129, 130, 158, 197, 198, 199, 500, 501]:
    print('%3i is in groups: %r' % (n, check(n)))
```

Comment: table lookups are always fast. You added a caveat `Assuming you have enough memory`. What is the space complexity of your approach?

Comment: extent*range_count where extent is largest-smallest value of all ranges and range_count is the number of ranges (Maximum).

Comment: if I understand correctly, `extent` for this example would be 500 and `range_count` would be 6

Comment: Yep. Times some constant and  in the worst case of large overlap of the ranges. Of course, if one new the exact ranges then you might modify a simple table lookup: If the table were sparse for example then you could trade memory for speed by using some form of sparse table structure but then all alternative solutions would need to compared for access speed and memory use for the actual set of ranges to be used. (P.S. Wot! no upvote? :-)

Comment: what if one particular range was `10k-15k` and others in `100s` range as in this example. Will you end up creating a large table?

Comment: It depends on how much memory is "large" and how much is "too large". You can use multiple algorithms choosing between them based on stats from the ranges themselves. If extent*range_count > limit do something else kind of thing.

Comment: fair enough. It would be fast when the `extent` is small enough to fit in cache/memory. If it is large then have to settle with other algorithms

Comment: This is indeed a fast solution, but one that potentially uses a lot of memory, since you are basically pre-computing every possible answer between `smallest` and `largest`. A simple problem with a single range [1, 1000000] will need to store 1 million points! And this solution cannot be used when the edges of the ranges would be floating points, instead of integers.

Comment: You need to tune your limit(s) to choose one of several routines with different speed/space tradeoffs. I coded two routines.